# Prevent Programs from Locking Keys?

Tags: keyboard, photoshop-cs4

Photoshop CS4 locks the <kbd>ESC</kbd> key while the program is open. Pushing the <kbd>ESC</kbd> key doesn't register while it's open except when pushing <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>ESC</kbd>.

Also, some games lock the volume control keys.

Is there any way to prevent programs from locking these keys or override the lock?

Answer (score 1):

Applications can program specific keys to perform actions. This is not uncommon and is usually limited to just a few keys. If a key appears "Locked" - in other words it doesn't perform its usual function - then the developer has either programmed it to perform some action in the program or to do nothing. The keyboard is still sending the keycode to the program, which is catching that keycode and handling it within the code.  You can't reprogram what the program code is doing. So the answer is NO.

Realize there may be a reason why the developer has made the effort to program the key. No developer is going to spend their time programming keys just to be annoying. The keys may be so disruptive within the program that it would be necessary to end the program if they were used. Of course, you can do that.